# Embed graph with predefined selected axis in CKAN

Tags: ckan

Is there any way to **define the axis** in the embebed iframe?

For example, I want to display following chart:

[image]

But when I click the `Embed` option, I get an interactive iframe to select the axis manually:

[image]

[Demo](https://demo.ckan.org/dataset/newcastle-city-council-spending-over-f250/resource/85da2a1c-9532-4d79-a917-102a8c951053)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by enabling the `recline_graph_view` plugin which will allow you to create graphs from data stored on the DataStore. Once it is enabled you will have a new Graph tab displayed next to the Data Explorer. As an example, you can check https://demo.ckan.org/dataset/sample-dataset-1/resource/9ce6650b-6ff0-4a52-9b10-09cfc29bbd7e?view_id=0b9d42ad-e594-4b2c-9146-9eca12da0df6.

Since this is on the same CKAN instance `recline_graph_view` is already enabled so you just need to create that view.